# Compare two objects of the same type for equality without public getters?

Tags: c++

I have a class with several members. I've so far successfully had no getters in my class which I like because I don't want people exposing the specifics of the class. I then had to compare two objects of this class for equality. I can't think of a way around creating several public getters. I really don't want to do this to keep encapsulation. Is there another way?

```cpp
class Foo
{
public:
    bool Equals( const Foo &other ) const;
private:
    bool x;
    // lots of other members
};

bool Foo::Equals( const Foo &other ) const
{
    // would I have to create and use public function other.GetX()?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own public equality member operator:

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        bool operator ==(Foo const& rhs) const
        {
            return x == rhs.x;
        }
};
```

Example of use:

```
Foo a, b;

assert(a == b);
```

Answer (score 2):

@0x499602D2 has already given a good answer that explains how to do this.

To add to that, I think the key point you haven't picked up yet is that access specifiers (`protected` and `private`) apply at the *class* level, not the *instance* level.  So one instance of a class can access private members of another instance.

Comment: Well, `protected` does apply at instance level, doesn't it?

Comment: @jrok: a `static` method of the class can access `protected` and `private` data of all classes, but I see what you mean. `protected` is just weird.

Comment: @jrok: Not sure what you mean.  You can still do `void foo(T &rhs) { this->x = rhs.x; }` even if `x` is `protected`...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth What I meant is [this](http://ideone.com/0vcqWD). A lot of people expect this to work. And it does work if `foo` takes a reference to `S` instead of `Base`. It is indeed a bit weird.

Comment: @jrok: Ah yes, agreed.  `protected` is complex once inheritance is involved!